# What does "a mix of" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I just want to be sure whether it means "a mix of economies" or "a mix of situations/conditions of ONE economy"?

"Growth across emerging market and developing economies in recent years once again displays heterogeneity – **a mix of tapering, standstills, reversals and continued strength in some cases**. This change has taken place against a backdrop of fading external tailwinds, including waningpotential growth in advanced economies, slowdown and rebalancing in China, and a shift in the commodity cycle that has affected commodity exporters," the Fund said in the report.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/04/10/imf-warns-protectionism-and-monetary-tightening-to-hurt-emerging-markets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighted part is explaining what the author means when they say "heterogeneity", which in itself applies to the "emerging market(s?) and developing economies".

Therefore it means **that there is a mixture of situations/conditions ([heterogeneity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heterogeneity)), which are then listed, that is displayed across the referred to "emerging market(s?) and developing economies".**

Answer (score 0):

It means: a mix of something, like slime is a mix of glue, borax and food color.

A mix of: a phrase talks about mix more than 1 thing and that mixture turn to another thing, liquid,...!

I hope this answer can help you!

Answer (score 0):

It means neither of the things you think it could mean.

It is not a "mix of economies" nor is it "one economy".

That mix of features (tapering, standstills, reversals, and sometimes continued strength) is the "heterogeneity" which is characteristic of the **growth** taking place in "emerging market (economies) and developing economies".